# Layout bug on question list page

Tags: bug

Not sure what's going on here. Seems to be the following div causing the problem:

```
<div class="everyonelovesstackoverflow" id="adzerk901722949"></div>
```

```
.everyonelovesstackoverflow:empty {
    height: 90px;
    width: 728px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

[image]

It only seems to be effecting the page when you filter by a tag.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5